# What skills do aviators have uniquely that could cross over to another industry?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance, pilots, human-factors

I have developed sensitivities to several chemicals used in aerospace. I have to make a shift away from our industry, so I would like to know what are qualities in aviators that would be unique and set us apart from other candidates in a good way. One that immediately comes to mind is our respect for inherent risk. What other tacit knowledge or soft skills apply?

Comment: Are you asking specifically about pilots? What kind of pilots? "Our industry" covers a lot of professions and a lot of variety within those professions.

Comment: Any aircrew would suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just asking but, have you thought about teaching PPL/ATPL? It's obviously not the same income as a pilot (usually), but you still keep in 'our industry' which I'm sure you really like the most.

Sorry about those sensitivities...